# How to keep a thread's message pump reactive

Tags: multithreading, delphi, winapi

I am implementing a thread that needs the following features:

1. Promptly responds to termination requests
2. Pumps messages
3. Remains responsive to SendMessage requests while waiting for a message

My initial implementation of the message pump used `GetMessage` like:

```
while not Terminated and GetMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0) do
begin
  TranslateMessage(Msg);
  DispatchMessage(Msg);
end;
```

The problem I found with that, is that GetMessage will never return unless there is a message.
Meaning, if there is low message activity, it may be quite a while before it checks `Terminated` again.

My second implementation (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7700970/2230115)) used `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` to wait until a message exists before checking (since it has a timeout)

```
while not Terminated do
begin
  if MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(0, nil^, False, 1000, QS_ALLEVENTS) = WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
  begin
    while PeekMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) do
    begin
      TranslateMessage(Msg);
      DispatchMessage(Msg);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The problem I've found with this, is that `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` blocks the thread while it waits. So, when a message is sent to the thread via `SendMessageTimeout`, it times out, where it doesn't when using `GetMessage`.

The solution that comes to mind is to go back to the `GetMessage` implementation, but add a timer to make sure a `WM_TIMER` message resets the loop every second.

Is this really the only way to do this?
It seems there should be some better way to keep the thread responsive while waiting for messages.

Comment: Use the first message loop and post a WM_NULL when you terminate the thread. That will be make GetMessage return immediately if it is blocking. Item 3 on your list of requirements should be removed. There is no point in being awake when there is nothing to do.

Comment: Item 3 refers to how `SendMessageTimout` requests are dropped while using `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`. It needs to be able to respond to these messages.

Comment: Not a problem with the solution sketched in my comment

Comment: I agree. I guess you're trying to say it was worded poorly. I've re-worded it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My initial implementation of the message pump used GetMessage like:
>
> ```
> while not Terminated and GetMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0) do
> begin
>   TranslateMessage(Msg);
>   DispatchMessage(Msg);
> end;
> ```
>
> The problem I found with that, is that GetMessage will never return unless there is a message. Meaning, if there is low message activity, it may be quite a while before it checks `Terminated` again.

You can override the thread's virtual [`TerminatedSet()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.TerminatedSet) method to *post* a message to the queue via `PostMessage()` or `PostThreadMessage()` to "wake up" `GetMessage()` if it is blocked.

Alternatively, have your thread constructor create a [`TEvent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.TEvent) object, and free it in the thread's destructor.  Then have `TerminatedSet()` signal that event.  Your loop can then use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` to wait on the message queue AND the event at the same time.  The return value will tell you whether the wait was satisfied by a message or the event.

> My second implementation (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7700970/2230115)) used `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` to wait until a message exists before checking (since it has a timeout)
>
> ```
> while not Terminated do
> begin
>   if MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(0, nil^, False, 1000, QS_ALLEVENTS) = WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
>   begin
>     while PeekMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) do
>     begin
>       TranslateMessage(Msg);
>       DispatchMessage(Msg);
>     end;
>   end;
> end;
> ```
>
> The problem I've found with this, is that `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` blocks the thread while it waits. So, when a message is sent to the thread via `SendMessageTimeout`, it times out, where it doesn't when using `GetMessage`.

The `SendMessage...()` family of functions will deliver a message directly to the target window's message procedure, bypassing the message queue completely. So `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` and `(Get|Peek)Message()` will never report a *sent* message from `SendMessage...()`, only a *posted* message from `PostMessage()` or `PostThreadMessage()` (or a synthesized message, like `WM_TIMER`, `WM_PAINT`, etc).  However, when *sending* a message across thread boundaries, the receiving thread still needs to perform message retrieval calls (is, `(Get|Peek)Message()`) in order for the *sent* message to actually be delivered to the window procedure.

> The solution that comes to mind is to go back to the `GetMessage` implementation, but add a timer to make sure a `WM_TIMER` message resets the loop every second.

Inside a thread, it would be better to use a [waitable timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/waitable-timer-objects) instead of `WM_TIMER`, then you can use the timer with `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()`.  But really, there is very little difference between using `GetMessage()` with `WM_TIMER` vs `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` with a timeout, so there is no need to waste system resources creating the timer.

Comment: Thanks! I like the idea of posting a message from `TerminatedSet` best.