# RawInput WinAPI: GetRawInputBuffer() and message handling

Tags: delphi, messaging, raw-input

**Why**
I'm trying to get input from a barcode scanner to my (visual) application. I would like to ignore input from other devices and get the input even if the application loses focus. I found the RawInput API recommended on SO and also elsewhere, to achieve this.

I've focused on [GetRawInputBuffer()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getrawinputbuffer) to read the input, as I'm expecting ~2 scans per second and ~700 events (key down / key up) triggered for each scan (assuming the scanner is acting as a keyboard). The documentation mentions to use GetRawInputBuffer() "for devices that can produce large amounts of raw input". I don't know whether the above actually qualifies...

**Problem**
I've successfully received input data - but there is something I must be doing wrong (possibly fundamentally...) as I can't figure out a good way to get consistent results. The raw data seems to 'disappear' very quickly and I often get no data back. There are similar existing questions on SO about GetRawInputBuffer() but they have only gotten me so far... Some notes:

- I use 'unRawInput.pas' from https://github.com/lhengen/RawInput
- I create a window handle using AllocateHwnd() and register it for raw input

(edit) **Question**
How/when should I (correctly) call GetRawInputBuffer() in a visual application to get consistent results, meaning e.g. *all* key events since the last call? Or: How/why do events seem to get 'discarded' between calls and how can I prevent it?

**Code**
The below code is a 64bit console application showcasing 3 approaches I've tried so far, and their problems (uncomment / comment-out approaches as described in code comments of the main begin-end.-block).

- approach #1: Sleep() while input is happening, then reading the buffer right away. I got the idea to Sleep() from [the learn.microsoft.com sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/using-raw-input#performing-a-buffered-read-of-raw-input) - and it works very well in that it seems to get all the input, but I don't think this is practical as my application needs to remain responsive.
- approach #2: use GetMessage() - usually, this yields no data, unless you type very quickly (like, mash keys) and even then, it's maybe 50% of input, tops.
- approach #3: use PeekMessage() and PM_NOREMOVE - this seems to get input very consistently but maxes out the thread.

```
program readrawbuffer;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  WinAPI.Windows,
  WinAPI.Messages,
  System.Classes,
  System.SysUtils,
  URawInput in '..\URawInput.pas';       // from: https://github.com/lhengen/RawInput

type
  TGetInput = class
  strict private
    fRawInputStructureSize: UINT;
    fRawInputHeaderSize: UINT;
    fRawInputBufferSize: Cardinal;
    fRawInputDevice: RAWINPUTDEVICE;
    fRawInputBuffer: PRAWINPUT;
    procedure RawInputWndProc(var aMsg: TMessage);
  public
    fRawInputWindowHnd: HWND;
    function ReadInputBuffer(): String;
    constructor Create();
    destructor Destroy(); override;
  end;

  constructor TGetInput.Create();
  begin
    inherited;
    fRawInputStructureSize := SizeOf(RAWINPUT);
    fRawInputHeaderSize := SizeOf(RAWINPUTHEADER);
    // create buffer
    fRawInputBufferSize := 40 * 16;
    GetMem(fRawInputBuffer, fRawInputBufferSize);
    // create handle and register for raw (keyboard) input
    fRawInputWindowHnd := AllocateHWnd(RawInputWndProc);
    fRawInputDevice.usUsagePage := $1;
    fRawInputDevice.usUsage := $6;
    fRawInputDevice.dwFlags := RIDEV_INPUTSINK;
    fRawInputDevice.hwndTarget := fRawInputWindowHnd;
    if RegisterRawInputDevices(@fRawInputDevice, 1, SizeOf(RAWINPUTDEVICE)) then
      WriteLn('device(s) registered; start typing...')
    else
      WriteLn('error registering device(s): ' + GetLastError().ToString());
  end;

  destructor TGetInput.Destroy();
  begin
    if Assigned(fRawInputBuffer) then
      FreeMem(fRawInputBuffer);

    DeallocateHWnd(fRawInputWindowHnd);
    inherited;
  end;

  function TGetInput.ReadInputBuffer(): String;
  var
    pcbSize, pcbSizeT: UINT;
    numberOfStructs: UINT;
    pRI: PRAWINPUT;

  begin
    Result := String.Empty;
    pcbSize := 0;
    pcbSizeT := 0;

    numberOfStructs := GetRawInputBuffer(nil, pcbSize, fRawInputHeaderSize);
    if (numberOfStructs = 0) then
    begin
      // learn.microsoft.com says for 'nil'-call: "minimum required buffer, in bytes, is returned in *pcbSize"
      // though probably redundant, I guess it can't hurt to check:
      if (fRawInputBufferSize < pcbSize) then
      begin
        fRawInputBufferSize := pcbSize * 16;
        ReallocMem(fRawInputBuffer, fRawInputBufferSize);
      end;

      repeat
        pcbSizeT := fRawInputBufferSize;
        numberOfStructs := GetRawInputBuffer(fRawInputBuffer, pcbSizeT, fRawInputHeaderSize);
        if ((numberOfStructs > 0) and (numberOfStructs < 900000)) then
        begin
          {$POINTERMATH ON}
          pRI := fRawInputBuffer;

          for var i := 0 to (numberOfStructs - 1) do
          begin
            if (pRI.keyboard.Flags = RI_KEY_MAKE) then
              Result := Result + pRI.keyboard.VKey.ToHexString() + #32;

            pRI := NEXTRAWINPUTBLOCK(pRI);
          end;
          {$POINTERMATH OFF}
          // DefRawInputProc();   // doesn't do anything? http://blog.airesoft.co.uk/2014/04/defrawinputproc-rastinating-away/
        end
        else
          Break;
      until False;

    end
  end;

  procedure TGetInput.RawInputWndProc(var aMsg: TMessage);
  begin
    // comment-out case block for Sleep() approach; leave last DefWindowProc() line
    // leave case block for GetMessage() / PeekMessage() -approaches; comment-out last DefWindowProc() line
//    case aMsg.Msg of
//      WM_INPUT:
//        begin
//          Write(ReadInputBuffer(), '-');
//          aMsg.Result := 0;
//        end
//    else
//      aMsg.Result := DefWindowProc(fRawInputWindowHnd, aMsg.Msg, aMsg.WParam, aMsg.LParam);
//    end;

    // comment-out for GetMessage() / PeekMessage() -approaches
    aMsg.Result := DefWindowProc(fRawInputWindowHnd, aMsg.Msg, aMsg.WParam, aMsg.LParam);
  end;


var
  getInput: TGetInput;
  lpMsg: tagMSG;

begin
  getInput := TGetInput.Create();


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// approach #1: Sleep()
// >> comment-out other aproaches; comment-out case block in RawInputWndProc(), leave last DefWindowProc() line

  repeat
    WriteLn('sleeping, type now...');
    Sleep(3000);
    WriteLn('VKeys read: ', getInput.ReadInputBuffer());
  until False;


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// approach #2: GetMessage()
// >> comment-out other approaches; comment-out last DefWindowProc() line in RawInputWndProc(), leave case block

//  repeat
//    // learn.microsoft.com: "Use WM_INPUT here and in wMsgFilterMax to specify only the WM_INPUT messages."
//    if GetMessage(lpMsg, getInput.fRawInputWindowHnd, WM_INPUT, WM_INPUT) then
//      DispatchMessage(lpMsg);
//  until False;


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// approach #3: PeekMessage()
// >> comment-out other approaches; comment-out last DefWindowProc() line in RawInputWndProc(), leave case block

//  repeat
//    if PeekMessage(lpMsg, getInput.fRawInputWindowHnd, WM_INPUT, WM_INPUT, PM_NOREMOVE) then
//      DispatchMessage(lpMsg);
//
//    if PeekMessage(lpMsg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) then
//      DispatchMessage(lpMsg);
//  until False;

  getInput.Free();
end.
```

Comment: Would be a better question if you asked one.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz: Thanks; edited

Comment: Thanks. The easy answer seems to be approach 1 in a thread.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz: I like it - I have almost no experience with multi-threading though (and heard it's not trivial...) so I may wait for some alternatives first

Comment: I wonder if you could do this with [the HID API](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/obtaining-hid-reports-by-user-mode-applications) though I'm not sure you can mark the input from the scanner device to no longer get processed into the input queue...

Answer (score 2):

**I've overhauled this 'answer' based on the exchange in the comments below and involved testing. It does not necessarily answer my question but represents my current level of understanding and outlines the approach I ended up taking (and which seems to be working so far)**

- RawInput seems to be sent through WM_INPUT window messages in any case; whether when using `GetRawInputData()` or `GetRawInputBuffer()`
- This means some kind of window is needed to which the messages can be sent to. This can be a hidden window. Using `CreateWindowEx(0, PChar('Message'), nil, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, 0, 0, nil);` works very well for me so far
- This also means that there needs to be a message loop of some kind so messages can be worked off (and don't pile up).
- The difference to `GetRawInputData()` seems to be that Windows will 'queue up' WM_INPUT messages and `GetRawInputBuffer()` gets and removes (from the queue) *multiple messages at once*. And I think the single advantage there is that input can be 'received in' quicker (higher throughput) this way than having to 'deal with every WM_INPUT message individually'.
- What's tricky is that it seems like for `GetRawInputBuffer()` to work, it's paramount that messages *except* WM_INPUT are handled by regular means - and then `GetRawInputBuffer()` gets called regularly, which deals with the queued-up WM_INPUT messages. Any approach I took which in some way 'looked' at WM_INPUT messages ultimately caused me to get inconsistent / incomplete results from `GetRawInputBuffer()`

Below is my message loop, which is largely inspired by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48602818/10839192) and runs in a separate thread

```
repeat
  TThread.Sleep(10);

  while True do
  begin
    if (Not PeekMessage(lpMsg, 0, 0, WM_INPUT - 1, PM_NOYIELD or PM_REMOVE)) then System.Break;
    DefWindowProc(lpMsg.hwnd, lpMsg.message, lpMsg.wParam, lpMsg.lParam);
  end;

  while True do
  begin
    if (Not PeekMessage(lpMsg, 0, WM_INPUT + 1, High(Cardinal), PM_NOYIELD or PM_REMOVE)) then System.Break;
    DefWindowProc(lpMsg.hwnd, lpMsg.message, lpMsg.wParam, lpMsg.lParam);
  end;

  ReadRawInputBuffer();     // shown below; essentially reads out all queued-up input
until SomeCondition;
```

Reading the buffer (largely inspired by the sample code on learn.microsoft.com):

````
procedure ReadInputBuffer();
var
  // ...

begin
  // this returns the minimum required buffer size in ```pcbSize```
  numberOfStructs := GetRawInputBuffer(nil, pcbSize, rawInputHeaderSize);
  if (numberOfStructs = 0) then
  begin
    // read out all queued-up data
    repeat
      // ... allocate pBuffer as needed
      numberOfStructs := GetRawInputBuffer(pBuffer, pcbSize, rawInputHeaderSize);
      if ((numberOfStructs > 0) and (numberOfStructs < 900000)) then
        // do something with pBuffer / its data
        // I use a TThreadedQueue<T>; the items/data is worked off outside this thread
      else
        System.Break;
    until False;
  end
end;
````

(In tests of over 10 minutes, reading in > 700'000 key events doesn't seem to have lost me a single one (if my numbers don't lie). Using `TStopWatch` and starting/stopping at the start of the message loop (after `TThread.Sleep(10)`) and stopping at the end after having exhausted the input queue, in one test reading about 12k events in 15 seconds (that's close to 800 events per second), the slowest run measured... 0ms.)

Comment: This looks wrong. You are retrieving the same WM_INPUT over and over and over again, because you never remove any message from the queue. That's probably why the message queue fills up, and it may be the reason why you don't see any other message than WM_INPUT.

Comment: Additionally you seem to mix the concepts of buffered and unbuffered reads. If you are processing WM_INPUT, read unbuffered because a single message has information of one RAWINPUT. I'm not familiar with buffered read but I don't think it is used with a message loop.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Thanks for your inputs. I agree it looks wrong. What's odd is that this 'works'. I get well past the ~10K event limit that I encountered when I ignored all messaging. The thing is, when I register for raw input, I 'need' to provide a window handle in the [RAWINPUTDEVICE structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-rawinputdevice) - it can be NULL: "A handle to the target window. If NULL it follows the keyboard focus." ...which seems like something I don't want. As handle I provide the window handle I get from `AllocateHWnd()`.

Comment: To `AllocateHWnd()` I also need to provide a window procedure, which for me currently is simply `DefWindowProc()`. What I mean by this is that I don't think I can _prevent_ Windows from sending me WM_INPUT messages. When I register, I cannot indicate that I intend to read input using `GetRawInputBuffer()` (I think). So this then implies I need to handle the WM_INPUT messages somehow even though `GetRawInputBuffer()` doesn't require them. As you and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19918968/10839192) state, it is called outside a message loop.

Comment: In contrast though, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48602818/10839192) implies there is a connection to WM_INPUT. And the [msdn sample](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/using-raw-input#performing-a-buffered-read-of-raw-input) seems to call `GetRawInputBuffer()` inside a 'private message'. It further adds this odd call to `DefRawInputProc()`, which [doesn't seem to do anything](http://blog.airesoft.co.uk/2014/04/defrawinputproc-rastinating-away/) - but implies _some cleanup_ needs to happen...? Edit: I've tried calling `DefRawInputProc()` but it didn't help..

Comment: At the bottom of [this shady page](https://theoldreader.com/profile/514169e5bd92795d6f000608?page=28) there is a partial / supposed / former blog entry by Timothy Lottes (game dev?) using an approach similar to the first SO answer: handling all messages _except_ WM_INPUT...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - Nope, you were right, this doesn't work. In a VM, it shows no apparent problems but on the host system we get stuck in the PeekMessage()-DispatchMessage()-Loop. Have now commented this out in the 'answer'.

Comment: Like I said, the first thing you should replace PM_NOREMOVE with PM_REMOVE.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Using `PM_REMOVE` in the loop as shown (now uncommented) in my answer generally works but we keep missing some inputs. Interestingly, we miss more as inputs are entered at a slower pace (casually / ~1 key press per second; misses >50% of inputs), whereas at approx. 700+ inputs per second, we miss <2%. If I use the 'Timothy Lottes' approach with `PeekMessage()` and `PM_REMOVE` for all messages _except_ WM_INPUT, we seem to be getting everything. `PeekMessage()` always returns 0 / False there.

Comment: Looks like there's no one to one correspondence between WM_INPUTs and actual inputs. I'd try leaving out the message loop (and the window) completely and sleeping in a loop in the thread for buffered reading. That would also mean coming back full circle to my comment to the question.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz No message loop and no window would certainly be my preferred option - but I don't think this works. [Here](https://pastebin.com/2TiWyMTT) is a cut-down but working version as a console app. Everything related to window messaging is commented-out. This does not yield any input at all...  I think it comes down to that the `RAWINPUTDEVICE` structure passed to `RegisterRawInputDevices()` has a `hwndTarget` member where the documentation says: _A handle to the target window. If NULL it follows the keyboard focus._  I pass NULL here because we have no window [cont]

Comment: [cont] In fact, I need to remove `RIDEV_INPUTSINK` (allowing for input capture without window focus) from the `dwFlags` member or registration fails (invalid parameters).

Comment: [cont] My theory: Raw input is always sent and received through WM_INPUT messages  - or not at all. The difference between `GetRawInputData()` and `GetRawInputBuffer()` is simply that a buffer is provided to the latter, allowing 'pickup' of multiple `RAWINPUT` structures at a time. Windows queues up messages but instead of dealing with one at a time, we do it in chunks. And for some reason, if we so much as 'consider carefully glancing' at any WM_INPUT messages in the queue, Windows no longer provides them in the buffer. [cont]

Comment: [cont] This 'explains', why explicitly dealing with any messages _other_ than WM_INPUT yields very consistent results and the queue does not seem to fill up (at least I get well past 10k events). I fully agree though that this isn't exactly intuitive (even with my very limited experience with windows messaging etc.). In fact, were it not for the one SO answer posted earlier and the 'Timothy Lottes' "blog", I'd consider this approach total bogus.

Comment: Is it plausible that with the previous approach using `while PeekMessage(lpMsg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) do` and inside the loop reading the buffer as well as calling `DispatchMessage(lpMsg)`, we missed some inputs because they were 'picked up' by `PeekMessage()` and 'handled' by `DispatchMessage()` and so were no longer available for the `GetRawInputBuffer()` reads? And we missed more for slower inputs because there were fewer in more time and so more were 'picked off' whereas with fast inputs, most results were received by reading the buffer.

Comment: Perhaps.. Easy to verify, move WM_INPUT handler and consequently the GetRawInputBuffer call to the window procedure. The likely explanation would be that these messages are *sent* to the window. Thanks for the follow up BTW..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I'm not sure I understand (or am doing this) correctly... [Here](https://pastebin.com/UugZDuL4) is my `WndProc()` and `TThread.Execute()`. Both are 'inspired' by [this (old) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7700970/10839192) by Remy (`AllocateHWnd()` not thread-safe...?).  Or what should I do in `Execute()`? Or do you mean don't use a thread to begin with? Anyways, results are very inconsistent - and the most I got was about 50% of inputs.  Idk, maybe I'm doing something else incorrectly here.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Ok, it stays interesting. I've cut everything down even more. No more thread, the 'window' is now a global variable (as is a bunch of other stuff) and reading the buffer is a global procedure. There are two versions: [Version 1](https://pastebin.com/Enw8Rt3W) uses the most general/basic `PeekMessage()` loop which calls `DispatchMessage()`. Let me know in case I've committed any grave sins here. The window procedure differentiates between WM_INPUT and everything else. _The 'else' case is never triggered_. [cont]

Comment: [cont] But if I set a breakpoint on the WM_INPUT case, it triggers _on the first key press_. And if I set the pass count to 50, it triggers very close to that (probably precisely, not that easy to tell). What's more: Very clearly, as keys are pressed more slowly, I get fewer events in the output - and more (to almost everything), for faster key presses. If I press at a very slow < 1 key / second, I can even get _no output at all_ - even though checking the buffer is the first thing done in the WM_INPUT case. [cont]

Comment: [cont] Now [Version 2](https://pastebin.com/g6AYCBRC). It's very similar except for the message handling and we read the buffer afterwards, not in the window procedure. Not only do we seem to get _every_ key event (from _4_ to ~_12'000_) but the window procedure never triggers.

Comment: Doing extended tests on a slightly modified variant of Version 2 that most notably uses `CreateWindowEx(0, PChar('Message'), nil, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, 0, 0, nil);` instead of `AllocateHWnd()` (as it is not thread-safe - though not relevant here) and defines _no_ window procedure to begin with, looks good so far. A 12 minute test during which over 540k events were recorded seemed to have gotten all events. Same with a 15 minute test and over 700k events (numbers add up). I will now move back to thread-based reading.